# Using Ruby, is it possible to print out BigDecimal("1") / BigDecimal("3") as 0.3333333333333... to any length?

Tags: ruby

If I do

```rb
require "bigdecimal"
"%60.50f" % [BigDecimal("1") / BigDecimal("3")]
=> "        0.33333333333333331482961625624739099293947219848633"
```

Is it possible to print out the result to any length with all `3`s at the end? (That is `0.333333333333...` to any length?)

Comment: Why not use `Rational` then? `Rational("1/3")` (as well as `Rational(1) / Rational(3)`) would give you what you are looking for...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are observing a loss of precision there because you are formatting the `BigDecimal` object to a Float first (because of your `f` format flag) which can't represent arbitrary precision floating point numbers.

However, you can use [`BigDecimal#to_s`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.2/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html#method-i-to_s) to format a `Bigdecimal` object as a string without any loss of precision. Here, the output will use as much precision as is available in the object you are formatting.

When creating your object with `BigDecimal#/`, it will use some predefined precision, on my box this was `36` on Ruby 3.1. This will result in 36 decimal numbers being printed by default:

```
result = BigDecimal("1") / BigDecimal("3")
result.precision
# => 36
result.to_s('F')
# => "0.333333333333333333333333333333333333"
```

If you desire higher precision in the resulting BigDecimal object after your division, you can use [`BigDecimal#quo`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.2/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html#method-i-quo) instead:

```
result = BigDecimal("1").quo(BigDecimal("3"), 60)
result.precision
# => 60
result.to_s('F')
# => "0.333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333"
```

Comment: `"%60.50f" % Rational(1, 3)` works fine though, despite `f`.

Comment: `Kernel#sprintf` (which is used by `String#%`) indeed [includes some special handling](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/cb4e2cb55a59833fc4f1f6db2f3082d1ffcafc80/sprintf.c#L790-L801) for formatting Rationals (and Integers) so that it effectively behaves as an arbitrary precision float here. Objects of all other classes however (including `BigDecimal`) are first converted to an actual Float by calling `to_f` on it.

Comment: Interesting. You could exploit those internals: create the result via `result = BigDecimal("1").div(BigDecimal("3"), 60)` and print it as `"%60.50f" % result.to_r`